# Pentaho DI - Getting all files from a folder where name come from previous step

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi

Using Get File Names component in kettle (Pentaho Data Integration), I'm trying to get all files names (regardless of extension) from a folder which name come from a previous step's filed, let's say folderName.

I'm not getting any content from the given folder unless when specifying a static folder with a wildcard.

What I want is to add  "Switch\ Case" component after "Get all files names" component which, depending on extension of a file, will redirect to the correct step.

[Get files Names configuration illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXXzD.png)

Comment: What is the issue: (a) that you do not get any content or (b) that the `Switch/Case` is not working as you want ?

Comment: I don't get any content from the "Get files names" component.

Comment: The `Switch/Case` check for exact match of strings, while `Filter rows` allows to match contains, starts-With and ends-with matching. Sometimes writing a series of 3-6 `Filters rows` is better than writing a `Switch/Case` with 60 cases.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are on you machine. For a distant server the process is almost the same.

1. Do NOT check the `File name is defined in a field` [nicely translated in `Nom fichier depuis champ`].
2. The `File or Directory` becomes editable, and you may press the `Browse` button on the right.
3. Select any file contained in the directory you want.
4. **Press the `Add` button**. This feeds the `Select files` table. Warning: Most of the time, this step is forgotten!
5. Press the `Show filename(s)` button at the bottom of the table. At this stage, you probably get only one file instead of the full directory.
6. Edit the `File/Directory` column and erase the character at the right of the rightmost \ [or / on linux], so that this column contains the directory name and not the filename. Put `.*` in the `Wildcard (RegExp)` column.
7. Check the `Show filename(s)` buton.
8. Repeat variant of step 6 until you have what you want.